# How to properly track Hibernate metrics with Micrometer?

Tags: java, hibernate, metrics, micrometer

I am using these two lines to register HibernateQueryMetrics and HibernateMetrics with our micrometer `MeterRegistry` but we aren't seeing any metrics being reported there.

```java
// Query execution and time metrics
HibernateQueryMetrics.monitor(meterRegistry, sessionFactory, service.getServiceName());

// Sessions, transactions, entities, and cache metrics
HibernateMetrics.monitor(meterRegistry, sessionFactory, service.getServiceName());
```

Even when testing locally and sending requests that will query the database, the registry does not list any Meters with an Id that contains "hibernate". We do see other meters like HikariCP meters, but nothing for Hibernate. This is my first time using micrometer `MeterBinder`s, so I'm inclined to believe I'm missing a few steps here.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the issue. In case anyone else is having similar troubles, I just had to enable generating statistics in the Hibernate config with `hibernate.generate_statistics: true`